# How to draw hierarchical menu control with asp.net 4.0 with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, c#, asp.net-4.0

I'm working with one news letter system.I am wondering how can i draw hierarchical menu control with JavaScript here is [article](https://chandradev.com/2011/07/03/how-to-bind-asp-net-menu-control-with-database/).

I tried it up with setting up my code as it is:

**App_Code / SooperFish.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Xsl;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Net;


/// <summary>
/// Summary description for NlevelMenu
/// </summary>
public class SooperFish
{
    string ConnectionString, ErrorMsg;

    public object ApiProcedure { get; private set; }
    public CredentialCache Credentials { get; private set; }

    public SooperFish()
    {
        //Read Connection String From web.config
        ConnectionString = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EASYMAILConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    }
    public string GenerateXmlFormat()
    {
        string SqlCommand;
        DataSet DbMenu;
        DataRelation relation;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        {

            SqlCommand = "SELECT[MenuID],[MenuName],[MenuLocation],[ParentMenuID] FROM [EASYMAIL].[dbo].[tbl_Menu_master] WHERE [type_id] = " + int.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Session["TypeID"].ToString()) + " AND [IsActive] = 1 ";

            DbMenu = new DataSet();

            SqlDataAdapter Adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlCommand, conn);

            Adapter.Fill(DbMenu);

            Adapter.Dispose();
        }

        DbMenu.DataSetName = "Menus";

        DbMenu.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";

        //create Relation Parent and Child
        relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild", DbMenu.Tables["Menu"].Columns["MenuID"], DbMenu.Tables["Menu"].Columns["ParentMenuID"], true);

        relation.Nested = true;

        DbMenu.Relations.Add(relation);

        return DbMenu.GetXml();
    }
    public string ExecuteXSLTransformation()
    {
        string HtmlTags, XsltPath;
        MemoryStream DataStream = default(MemoryStream);
        StreamReader streamReader = default(StreamReader);

        try
        {
            //Path of XSLT file
            XsltPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("XsltFormatFolder/XsltTransformer.xslt");

            //Encode all Xml format string to bytes
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(GenerateXmlFormat());

            DataStream = new MemoryStream(bytes);

            //Create Xmlreader from memory stream

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(DataStream);

            // Load the XML 
            XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(reader);


            XslCompiledTransform XsltFormat = new XslCompiledTransform();

            // Load the style sheet.
            XsltFormat.Load(XsltPath);

            DataStream = new MemoryStream();

            XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(DataStream, Encoding.ASCII);


            //Apply transformation from xml format to html format and save it in xmltextwriter
            XsltFormat.Transform(document, writer);

            streamReader = new StreamReader(DataStream);

            DataStream.Position = 0;

            HtmlTags = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

            return HtmlTags;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorMsg = ex.Message;
            return ErrorMsg;
        }
        finally
        {
            //Release the resources 

            streamReader.Close();

            DataStream.Close();
        }


    }
}
```

**MenuControl.ascx**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MenuControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="MenuControl"%>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sooperfish.css" media="screen"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/sooperfish-theme-large.css" media="screen"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing-sooper.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sooperfish.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('ul.sf-menu').sooperfish();
        });
    </script>
    <asp:Literal  ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

**MenuControl Code**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
using AjaxControlToolkit;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;
using OpenPop.Pop3;
using OpenPop.Mime;
using OpenPop.Mime.Header;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.XPath;
using System.Xml.Resolvers;

public partial class MenuControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            SooperFish spoorfishMenu = new SooperFish();
            Literal1.Text = spoorfishMenu.ExecuteXSLTransformation();
        }
    }
}
```

How ever this not work me out because 500 Internal Error Occurs while web request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok. it's solved by this code without using web request;

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text;
public partial class MenuControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Menu1.MenuItemClick += new MenuEventHandler(Menu1_MenuItemClick);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            PopulateMenu(this.GetData(), 0, null);
        }
    }
    public DataTable GetData(int parentMenuId)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MenuID", typeof(int)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MenuName", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MenuLocation", typeof(string)));
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            var menu = db.Menus.Where(m => m.ParentMenuID.Equals(parentMenuId) && m.IsActive.Equals(true)).Select(m => new { MenuID = m.MenuID, MenuTitle = m.MenuName, MenulLocation = m.MenuLocation }).ToList();
            foreach (var menuItem in menu)
            {
                if (menuItem != null)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                    dr["MenuID"] = menuItem.MenuID;
                    dr["MenuName"] = menuItem.MenuTitle.ToString();
                    dr["MenuLocation"] = menuItem.MenulLocation.ToString();
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                }
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
    public void PopulateMenu(DataTable dt, int parentMenuId, MenuItem parentMenuItem)
    {
        string currentPage = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem { Value = row["MenuID"].ToString(), Text = row["MenuName"].ToString(), NavigateUrl = row["MenuLocation"].ToString(), Selected = row["MenuLocation"].ToString().EndsWith(currentPage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) };
            if (parentMenuId == 0)
            {
                Menu1.Items.Add(menuItem);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(menuItem.Value));
                PopulateMenu(dtChild, int.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem);
            }
            else
            {
                parentMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(menuItem);
            }
        }
    }
    public DataTable GetData()
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("Menu");
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MenuID", typeof(int)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MenuName", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MenuLocation", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ParentMenuID", typeof(int)));
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["MenuID"] = "1";
            dr["MenuName"] = "Home";
            dr["MenuLocation"] = "~/User_Landing_Page.aspx";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            foreach (var item in db.Menus.Where(m => m.IsActive.Equals(true) && m.type_id.Equals(int.Parse(Session["TypeID"].ToString())) && m.ParentMenuID == null).Select(m => new
            {
                MenuID = m.MenuID,
                MenuName = m.MenuName,
                MenuLocation = m.MenuLocation,
                ParentMenuID = m.ParentMenuID
            }).ToList())
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
                    dr1["MenuID"] = int.Parse(item.MenuID.ToString());
                    dr1["MenuName"] = item.MenuName.ToString();
                    if (item.MenuLocation != null)
                    {
                        dr1["MenuLocation"] = item.MenuLocation.ToString();
                    }
                    if (item.ParentMenuID != null)
                    {
                        dr1["ParentMenuID"] = int.Parse(item.ParentMenuID.ToString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dr1["ParentMenuID"] = 0;
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr1);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }

    protected void Menu1_MenuItemClick(object sender, MenuEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Item.Selected.ToString())
        {
            case "Compose Mail":
                Session["flag"] = "1";
                Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
            case "From User Master":
                Session["flag"] = "2";
                Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
            case "Subscriber Master":
                Session["flag"] = "3";
                Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
            case "Import Susbcribers":
                Session["flag"] = "4";
                Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
            default:
                Session["flag"] = "0";
                Response.Redirect(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```